# Is it MonoDevelop's bug?

Tags: ide, monodevelop

I use Debian Squeeze and MonoDevelop 2.4 for my program and I have some problems with it. When I trying to save my project's changes, I have next message dialog of MonoDevelop:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>     at MonoDevelop.GtkCore.GuiBuilder.CodeBinder.IsValidClass (MonoDevelop.Projects.Dom.Parser.ProjectDom ctx, IType cls, Stetic.Component obj) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at MonoDevelop.GtkCore.GuiBuilder.CodeBinder.GetClass (Boolean getUserClass) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at MonoDevelop.GtkCore.GuiBuilder.CodeBinder.GetClass () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at MonoDevelop.GtkCore.GuiBuilder.CodeBinder.UpdateBindings (System.String fileName) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at MonoDevelop.GtkCore.GuiBuilder.GuiBuilderView.Save (System.String fileName) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Document.Save () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at MonoDevelop.Ide.Gui.Workbench.SaveAll () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at MonoDevelop.Ide.Commands.SaveAllHandler.Run () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandHandler.Run (System.Object dataItem) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandHandler.InternalRun (System.Object dataItem) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandManager.DefaultDispatchCommand (MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.ActionCommand cmd, MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandInfo info, System.Object dataItem, System.Object target, CommandSource source) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at MonoDevelop.Components.Commands.CommandManager.DispatchCommand (System.Object commandId, System.Object dataItem, System.Object initialTarget, CommandSource source) [0x00000] in :0

When I trying to add some event for my project's form, I have the same. What does it mean and how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use latest Mono and latest MonoDevelop,

http://pkg-mono.alioth.debian.org/ (3.0.6)

http://monodevelop.com/Download (4.0.8)

MonoDevelop 2.4.* was two years ago,

http://monodevelop.com/Download/MonoDevelop_2.4.2_Released?highlight=2.4+release+notes

Comment: Yes, I know, but official repository of Debian Squeeze contains MonoDevelop 2.4. And next official Mono's document contains the same: http://mono-project.com/DistroPackages/Debian